# How to check in Bash if the first 10 files which end in 1 through 10 exist in bash without needing a loop?

Tags: bash

I have files which exist as `File.Iteration.${i}.txt` where `${i}` is a number. I would like to check if files `File.Iteration.1.txt` through `File.Iteration.10.txt` exist. If it does, within a loop I would like to trigger `continue`. I know I can do:

```
for((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do 
    name="File.Iteration.${i}.txt"
    [[ -e "$name" ]] && break
done
```

which is rather terse. Is there a simpler way to do this, preferably in one line?

Comment: `[[ -e "$name" ]] && continue` is pointless, it will continue anyway. What exactly are you checking with this code?

Comment: Sorry! I mean `break`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for nonzero exit status of:

```
ls File.Iterator.{1..10}.txt >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: How can I check for the non-zero exit status? I went through a list of file test operators, but didn't find it.

Comment: `if` is literally the "command" that checks exit status of another command.  `if ls File.Iterator.{1..10}.txt >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo something; else echo something; fi`